# Sublime text 3 wrong auto complete on </ inside <script>

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, sublimetext3, auto-close

I want to write this code:

```
<script type="text/jsx">
    var MessageBox = React.createClass({

        render: function() {
            return <div>Hello World</div>
        }
    });
</script>
```

When I typing `</` in line `return <div>Hello World</` Sublime auto-closes tag to `</script>` instead of `</div>`.

This is very annoying while coding using JSX style (react.js)

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I think you can turn off the predictions but while looking at your source code your return should be wrapped in single or double quotes. `return '<div>Hello World</div>';` only time you don't need to wrap the return is if it's true/false or a variable you want to return.

Comment: @NewToJS i don't think that's plain old javascript. It's text/jsx, which gets transformed to plain javascript i think.

Comment: @KevinB so when the function gets to the return it wouldn't display `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` in the console?

Comment: Not entirely sure, i've never used the jsx transformer. The getting started demo shows something similar: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: So it does, my apologies! (*Makes note of that one*) Well, we all make mistakes but thank you for the heads up on that one @KevinB

Comment: @pupadupa have you tried this sublime extension? https://github.com/reactjs/sublime-react

Comment: @KevinB Thank you! This extension solves the problem!